# In EF Core 5, how to apply Groupby after applying FirstOrDefault in parent Query

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-5.0, ef-core-5.0

I am working on .NET 5 CORE app with Entity Framework Core 5.0.6 Version.

Ultimately, I need to group my record. In EF CORE 3, I was able to use group by on script before applying ToList() but I believe is not possible in EF Core 5. So to achieve group by, I am intended to pull record and then apply group by on it.. Unless there is a better way?

```
var contraventionImages = (from contravention in db.Contraventions
                  join contraventionGuideImage in db.ContraventionGuideImages on contravention.ContraventionId equals contraventionGuideImage.ContraventionId into con_guide_img
                  from contraventionGuideImages in con_guide_img.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  join image in db.GuideImages on contraventionGuideImages.GuideImageId equals image.GuideImageId into guide_img
                  from guideImages in guide_img.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  where contravention.ContraventionId == ContraventionId
                  select new ContraventionGuideImageView
                  {
                     Contravention = contravention,
                     ContraventionGuideImages = contraventionGuideImages,
                     GuideImages = guideImages
                  })
                  .FirstOrDefault()
                  ;
```

So I have pulled the record, ending script with FirstOrDefault(), now in second script where I am trying to inspect and group Item; is Unable to do so. I am not able to apply select on query result I have in previous step

[image]

```
 public class ContraventionGuideImageView
{
    public Contravention Contravention { get; set; }
    public ContraventionGuideImage ContraventionGuideImages { get; set; }
    public GuideImage GuideImages { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware you can still use `.ToList()`

Comment: But I am expect single record and not collection so why should I use ToList()

Comment: I was merely pointing out that the thing you said you thought wasn't possible, is. However in this scenario, it looks more like the definition of `ContraventionGuideImageView` is causing your issue.

Comment: If I remove ContraventionGuideImageView fom script one then in script 2 then it throw exception .. could not find an implementation of the query patter for source type 'Contravention'  select not found

Comment: How is `ContraventionGuideImageView` defined - what is `Contravention`?

Comment: I have update question with ContraventionGuideImageView defination

Comment: @Toxic what are you trying to do in the first place? EF Core and LINQ aren't embedded SQL or an alternative to SQL. Instead of JOINs between tables, you use *relations* between *entities* and let the ORM generate the JOINs. The query you posted is far harder to read than a SQL query and definitely not a good LINQ query. If you find the need to use `ToList()`, you're doing it wrong. ORMs are meant to Map Objects to Relational tables anyway, not replace SQL in complex analytical queries. What you want could be solved in SQL using analytic functions like `ROW_NUMBER()`, `FIRST_VALUE()`, etc

Comment: the "second scriipt" it makes little sense. `contraventionImages` is a *single object*. So is `Contravention`. It makes no sense to try to query a single object.  Just writing `var x=contraventionImages.Contravention`.

Comment: Are you trying to load a `Contravention` object and all relates entities? If you use proper relation you'd only need `_context.Contraventions.Find(someId)` to load the root object and lazily load any `...Image` objects as you access them. Or `_context.Contraventions.Include(c=>c. GuideImages).Include(c=>...).Where(c=>c.ContraventionID=someId)` to eagerly load them in a single query. EF Core would take care of reconstructing the object graph

Answer (score 0):

OK, the edit has made it much clearer to see. It looks like your confusion is that after selecting the first record you're trying to do further queries on that record which:

1. Won't work
2. Seems pointless.

By doing the call to `FirstOrDefault`, you're getting an object (in your case `ContraventionGuideImageView`); you need to do any grouping/ordering on the queryable before you do the first or default, for example:

```
var contraventionImages = (from contravention in db.Contraventions
                  join contraventionGuideImage in db.ContraventionGuideImages on contravention.ContraventionId equals contraventionGuideImage.ContraventionId into con_guide_img
                  from contraventionGuideImages in con_guide_img.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  join image in db.GuideImages on contraventionGuideImages.GuideImageId equals image.GuideImageId into guide_img
                  from guideImages in guide_img.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  where contravention.ContraventionId == ContraventionId
                  select new ContraventionGuideImageView
                  {
                     Contravention = contravention,
                     ContraventionGuideImages = contraventionGuideImages,
                     GuideImages = guideImages
                  })
                  .ToList() //shouldn't make a difference, but is for the benefit of Toxic seeing the process.
                  .GroupBy(x => x.contravention)
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

HOWEVER, the query is so complex that I'd argue it'd be better as a stored procedure.

Comment: The query is complex because EF Core is misused. If the entities had proper relations there would be no need for those JOINs, they'd be generated by the ORM itself. It looks like `_context.Contraventions.Find(someId)` would be enough to load the root object and lazily load related entities, or `.Include(c=>c.GuideImages)...` to eagerly load them

Comment: While I agree that the proper relations would improve it, the amount of tables involved does lead me to believe the stored proc would be better (for maintainability, if nothing else)

Comment: I cannot do  grouping/ordering before selecting data i.e. ToList() in EF Core 5, is different than EF Core 3.0

Comment: I can do Include but do nt like it

Comment: @Toxic whether you like it or not is somewhat irrelevant when it comes to making things work.

Comment: How would writing the full SQL query be more maintainable? The query only joins a main table with 3 relations. With EF Core, there's no need to write any JOINs

Comment: @Toxic `I can do Include but do nt like it ` why don't you like it? What you tried is far more complex and doesn't even work. If you want to write explicit JOINs, why use EF core *at all*? With EF Core you wouldn't have to write anything except the `Where` call

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if a tweak is needed in future, you're committing to a code-change this way; whereas if it's a stored proc, you can change any grouping/ordering without having to rebuild/recompile so long as the structure of the resultset is still the same and parameters haven't changed.

Comment: You just described ORMs. In this case, the query is trying to do what an ORM already does far better- load a root entity and its related entities. You *can't* use a single SQL query or stored procedure to do the same. That's why this query is so complex already. It would be little better in a stored procedure and would *still* not load individual entities. You'd need *multiple* `SELECT` queries to load from each entity, then recombine the objects by hand

Comment: A *view*, not stored procedure, can be used to abstract the underlying tables. An ORM can use views instead of tables without problems.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos in my experience, views can get unwieldly quickly (especially if you reference them in stored procedures) due to the inability to apply indexes to them. As for the multiple `SELECT` queries bit, I'm confused what you mean there - if it's just doing what's suggested in the question, you don't need multiple `SELECT`s

Comment: `due to the inability to apply indexes to them` that's 100% wrong. For starters, the underlying indexes *are* used. Second, you *can* create indexes on tables, it's a common way to accelerate performance in large reporting databases. `you don't need multiple SELECTs` you misunderstood the (confusing) question then. This code is trying to load the entities related to a specific `Contraventions` item. The results are flat since `JOINs` are used so the code tries to generate proper objects again through that `GroupBy` and `FirstOrDefault`. This can't be done like this though

Comment: You can index tables, yes. Whether they're used in EF created views, I don't know - but they don't seem to work well in SQL views. As for the multiple `SELECTS`, fair enough in that case, he'd have to JSON it up if he wanted to spit it out of the DB in one block

Answer (score 0):

found the answer;

Option A:

```
   var t7 = (from contravention in db.Contraventions
                   .Include(x => x.ContraventionGuideImages)
                   .ThenInclude(x => x.GuideImage)
                  where contravention.ContraventionId == ContraventionId
                  select new
                  {
                      contravention = contravention,
                      GuideImages = contravention.ContraventionGuideImages.Select(x => x.GuideImage)
                  }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Option B:

```
 var contraventionImages = (from contravention in db.Contraventions
                  join contraventionGuideImage in db.ContraventionGuideImages on contravention.ContraventionId equals contraventionGuideImage.ContraventionId into con_guide_img
                  from contraventionGuideImages in con_guide_img.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  join image in db.GuideImages on contraventionGuideImages.GuideImageId equals image.GuideImageId into guide_img
                  from guideImages in guide_img.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  where contravention.ContraventionId == ContraventionId
                  select new { contravention, contraventionGuideImages, guideImages }).ToList();


var guideImagesList = (from contravention in contraventionImages.Select(x => x.contravention)
                  group contraventionImages.Select(x => x.guideImages ) by contravention into groupedItem
                  select new
                  {
                      contravention = groupedItem.Key,
                      contraventionGuideImages = groupedItem.ToList()

                  }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: The real answer is to use proper relations. That's 20 lines more than what you needed and probably 20 times slower as well

Comment: I do have properly relationship setup and have pull data using include and ThenInclude()...  behind the code is doing same thing then what make you say performance issue ? I have more control of what I want to map in earlier stage then later